# Docker Misbehaving on ubuntu 18.04 behind squid proxy

Tags: networking, server, proxy, docker, squid

I have 3 servers behind an squid proxy. On all of them , proxy works without any problem for all sites , but, http://registry-1.docker.io , works just on one of the servers. All `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf` configurations are the same , and I get this error on the two other servers :

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial
tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving
```

Is there any way to check the problem ?

Comment: Can you please manually run ```systemd-resolve registry-1.docker.io``` on the two problematic machines and post the output ? I think the problem might not be a DNS **server misbehavior** , but rather the inability to resolve that address via your DNS server perhaps because of some restrictions.

Comment: On the machine which works correctly : 
"registry-1.docker.io: resolve call failed: No appropriate name servers or networks for name found"

Comment: On the machine which not works :
"registry-1.docker.io: 3.223.220.229
                      3.211.199.249
                      23.22.155.84
                      18.232.227.119
                      3.218.162.19
                      18.213.137.78
                      107.23.149.57
                      54.85.107.53

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 130.5ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
"

Comment: totally weird problem !

Comment: By changing the /etc/hosts ip address, the error turned into this : 
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Comment: What about your ```/etc/squid/squid.conf``` file ? Do you have any suspicious configurations on them ? You can whitelist the port 53 in it via ```acl Safe_ports port 53```.Does it make a difference ? Also you can restart the squid server on those two machines. It might be a problem with caching.

Comment: I don't have any access to the squid server , as I said, one of my servers works correctly via the proxy server, So it seems there is no problem with proxy

Comment: Do you want to pull an image via **docker** ? There are reported problems centered around docker DNS . It might be one of them. The error message was exactly what you posted. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056365/error-get-https-registry-1-docker-io-v2-net-http-request-canceled-while-b). That problem got solved by using another DNS server in the docker configurations.

Comment: correct , but I have to approve to the Senior manager that the current configuration does not works, so when on one server I can connect with this configuration and on the other , I can't get connected , the problem gets weird . Also , I have to ask again for whitelisting 8.8.8.8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109469/discussion-between-alimahdavi-and-parsa-mousavi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by editing my IP4 DNS settings. I had `9.9.9.9`, `1.1.1.1`, `8.8.8.8`.

Changed the UI IP4 settings to `1.1.1.1`, `8.8.8.8`.

I ran:

```
systemd-resolve registry-1.docker.io
```

and I get:

```
 -- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 139.6ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
lar@lar:~$ kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server master:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

At least I don't get a DNS issue like before